# How to set the DjangoRestFramework permissin_classes relationship to `or`?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a `AmodelCreateAPIView` APIView:

```
class AmodelCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = AmodelSerializer
    permission_classes = [TokenHasReadWriteScope, TokenHasScope]
    queryset = Amodel.objects.all()
```

as all we know the `permission_classes` list relationship is `and`, how can I let them become `or`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `check_permissions()` method as below

try this

```
class AmodelCreateAPIView(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = AmodelSerializer
    permission_classes = [TokenHasReadWriteScope, TokenHasScope]
    queryset = Amodel.objects.all()

    def check_permissions(self, request):
        if not any(permission.has_permission(request, self) for permission in self.get_permissions()):
            self.permission_denied(
                request, message="some message"
            )
```

The [Orginal Souce code of `check_permissions()`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/views.py#L328) was as

> ```
> def check_permissions(self, request):
>     """
>     Check if the request should be permitted.
>     Raises an appropriate exception if the request is not permitted.
>     """
>     for permission in self.get_permissions():
>         if not permission.has_permission(request, self):
>             self.permission_denied(
>                 request, message=getattr(permission, 'message', None)
>             )
> ```

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to create a third permission class called

**TokenHasReadWriteORTokenHasScope**

and handle it inside the permission class. You can inherit from the two classes which you already got and implement the 'OR' logic.

It is similar approach to how DRF implements some permissions - example is **IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly**